# Tmux 3.0a how to past command line under Ubuntu 20.0.4

Tags: paste, tmux, ubuntu-20.04

I tried to copy and paste command line in tmux3.0a, under Ubuntu 20.0.04.
First, i highlight the text, but somehow the highlight disappear right away.
Then a list show up, from which there is a "copy" for me to choose.

Say i copy the directory like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvcEf.png)

Here is my problem:
How do i do the paste now (there is no paste option in that list)?? Because whatever tricks i used doesnot work anymore...
I have tried Middlebutton the mouse, right click mouse, C-v..etc.

Answer (score 0):

When I paste into the terminal, I must use ctrl+shift+v

Answer (score 0):

When working in the terminal and tmux..

I simply use the default `.tmux.conf` and when I need to copy paste things I highlight them and hold down `shift` key.. then right-click `copy` or `paste`